# Fatal error: Cannot redeclare yoast_breadcrumb() wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theme, wordpress-plugin

Tengo problemas con este sitio
http://qkstudiodemo.com/fundacionlomanegra/web/ me esta tirando un error pero no se porque motivos lo puede hacer, si bien en el function tenia declarado esto; lo borre por completo y me sigue tirando el error. O puede ser problemas de cache del servidor donde este trabajando sino.

```js
function yoast_breadcrumb() {
if (!is_home()) {
    echo '<span><a href="';
    echo get_option('home');
    echo '">';
    echo "Inicio";
    echo "</a><i class='fa fa-chevron-right' aria-hidden='true'></i>";
    if (is_category() || is_single()) {
        echo '<a href="';
        echo the_permalink();
        echo '">';
        the_category('title_li=');
        echo "</a></span>";
        if (is_single()) {
            echo '<a href="';
            echo the_permalink();
            echo '">';
            echo the_title();
            echo "</a><i class='fa fa-chevron-right' aria-hidden='true'></i>";
        }
    } elseif (is_page()) {
        echo '<a href="';
        echo the_permalink();
        echo '">';
        echo the_title();
        echo "</a>";
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Según la documentación, no parece ser un problema de cache.

Aquí se explica que:

> Su tema u otro complemento incluye nuestra clase de migas de pan , y
>   no está envolviendo class_exists o envolviendo adecuadamente
>   function_exists. La parte del  del error anterior normalmente
>   debería indicarle en un directorio de temas o complementos,
>   indicándole qué complemento es el culpable.
>
> La clase de migas de pan en nuestro complemento se mantiene, mientras
>   que la clase de migas de pan que se envía con el tema probablemente
>   esté desactualizada. Por lo tanto, consulte con el creador de su tema
>   y envíelos a esta página.

Y dice que para corregirlo:

> Debería envolver la clase y las funciones en class_exists o
>   function_exists wrappers. O, mejor aún, no debe incluirlo en absoluto
>   y solo decirle a la gente que instale nuestro complemento Yoast SEO y
>   usar las migas de pan proporcionadas por nuestro complemento, ya que
>   están mucho más actualizadas y realmente funcionan con tipos de
>   publicaciones personalizadas, tipo de publicación personalizada
>   archivos, etc.

Suerte

Comment: Es un tema que arme yo desde cero. si quito yoast directamente desde el FTP calculo que se arreglaria no?

Comment: Tendrías que probarlo